# JavaFx: will TableView suffice or do I need custom controller

Tags: java, javafx, controls, tableview

I'm currently making an application that helps me schedule meetings with an easy to use drag and drop system. All business logic is implemented, but I'm in doubt about the UI.

[Mockup of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c71W1.png)

Can this be implemented using the JavaFx TableView? My doubts originate from each row not being of a uniform height aswell as the data in each row doesn't belong together, however the data in each column does. If Tableview is not useful for this, how do I best approach this (other control, custom controls, ...), I'm fairly new to JavaFx.

thanks in advance, if extra information is required, I'm looking forward to deliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TableView` is probably not what you want here. `TableView`s represent tabular data, and as you've observed, they are "row-centric", in the sense that each row represents a particular data item. Your data structure does not fit this model well.

You probably want to start with a `GridPane` ([Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html), [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY118)), and see if that does what you need.

One other note: the [JFXtras library](http://jfxtras.org/) has an "Agenda" control. I have never used this, but it might save you from re-inventing the wheel.